# Hide gridlines in chartjs without the drawTicks

Tags: chart.js

I am creating a chart using `chart.js`. I would like to remove the gridlines, but I want to keep the little `pieces(`drawTicks: true`)`, marked yellow in the image below.

Is this be possible?

I have tried:

```
gridLines: {
   display: false,
   drawTicks: true
}
```

But that is hiding all of the gridlines.

[image: Line chart in chart.js]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can,
to hide the gridlines without removing the little ticks you can do this :

```
 gridLines: {
     drawOnChartArea: false
 }
```